# How to execute when between heights using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to alert someone but only when the scroll height is between a curtain height.

For instance.

When the person scrolls between 2000 pixels and 2500 pixels

I know how to do greater and smaller but how to do between?

```
var currentscroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

if(currentscroll > 2000){
alert('this');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currentscroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

if((currentscroll > 2000) && (currentscroll < 2500)){
alert('this');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that:

```
if(currentscroll > 2000 && currentscroll < 2500){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (currentScroll > 2000 && currentScroll < 2500)
```

?